# 'line' could not be a variable or function name Script 'Advanced RSI Strtg' has been saved

Tags: syntax-error, pine-script

Error what I get while code compiling/saving have pasted below
**"line 25: 'line' could not be a variable or function name
Script 'Advanced RSI Strtg' has been saved"**

Please find Codeing as follow.........

```
//@version=3

Stratagy(title="Shekhar", shorttitle="RSI", overlay=true)

//input
src = input(source=close, title="Source")
rsi_len = input(14, minval=1,title="RSI Length")
rsi_fast_len = input(5, minval=1,title="Fast RSI Length")
rsi_ema_len = input(14, minval=1,title="EMA Length")
overbought = input(70, minval=1,title="Overbought")
oversold = input(30, minval=1,title="Oversold")

//Logic
rsi = rsi(source, rsi_len)
rsi_fast = rsi(source, rsi_fast_len)
rsi_ema = ema(source, rsi_ema_len)

//colour
color_short = #FF5252
color_long = #64FFDA
color_neutral = #FFD600

p_rsi = plot(rsi, title="RSI", style=line, linewidth=3, transp=0, color = rsi > 50 ? aqua : white)
p_rsi_fast = plot(rsi_fast, title="Fast RSI", style=style.line, linewidth=2, transp=100, color=color_neutral)
p_rsi_ema = plot(rsi_ema, title="EMA", style=line, linewidth=1, transp=20, color=color_neutral)
fill(p_rsi, p_rsi_fast, color = rsi_fast > rsi_ema ? color_long : coor_short, transp=60, title="RSI Cloud Fill")

p_ob = plot(overbought, title="RSI Overbought", style=line, transp=50, linewidth=1, color=white)
p_os = plot(oversold, title="RSI Oversold", style=line, transp=50, linewidth=1, color=white)

p_base = plot(50, title="Base Line", style=line, transp=10, linewidth=1, color=color_neutral)
```

Comment: `style="line"` I would guess. Likewise you want `"aqua"` and `"white"` in quotes as these are strings, not variables.

Answer (score 0):

This is proper syntax for v3 and v4. Choose one:

```
//@version=3
study("")
rsi = rsi(close, 14)
p_rsi = plot(rsi, title="RSI", style=line, linewidth=3, transp=0, color = rsi > 50 ? aqua : white)
```

or

```
//@version=4
study("")
rsi = rsi(close, 14)
p_rsi = plot(rsi, title="RSI", style=plot.style_line, linewidth=3, transp=0, color = rsi > 50 ? color.aqua : color.white)
```

When posting code, please include the Pine version you are using (the first line in these snippets).